# Amplitude of electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism

For an EM wave propagating in +z direction, it is described by

$ \underline{E} = \underline{E_0}(x, y)e^{i(kz - wt)}$

I know that the imaginary term in the expression describes phase and $|\underline{E_0}|$ is the maximum amplitude of $\underline{E}$ and is a constant. But in general can $\underline{E_0}$ be complex as well? Or it is defined in the way that it cannot be? Is a complex $\underline{E_0}$ physical at all?

Answer (score 0):

When you get $|E_0|$ that means $sqrt(E_0E^*_0)$ its always a real value, that means the Amplitude $|E_0|$ is physical.